# What is the system effect of starting large quantities of timers in Java?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

recently I have had to program some applications that require large amounts of timed tasks to occur.  However, I'm afraid to create so many timers because I haven't been able to figure out how they are handled by Java.  Is there a problem with starting large quantities of scheduled tasks?  If so, what is the better alternative?

Comment: Hm... I think I don't understand your question yet... Can't you just use one timer and use it for all of the tasks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean one timer and a lot of tasks, the Javadocs for `Timer` say:

> Implementation note: This class scales
>   to large numbers of concurrently
>   scheduled tasks (thousands should
>   present no problem). Internally, it
>   uses a binary heap to represent its
>   task queue, so the cost to schedule a
>   task is O(log n), where n is the
>   number of concurrently scheduled
>   tasks.

Note that there is only one thread that runs the tasks.  If you need a lot of timers or more threads to run at once, you should look at `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem that I can think of. But you may want to read this:

[Timers](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=160)

and this:

[Schedule periodic tasks](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=CADB3B0A0DB64CDE8DD4B64FB8282EF0?Id=54)